# Excel VBA conditional row merging

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a VB code but I have to do this since I was in college.

I have the excel worksheet shown in image1 and I need to create a code that will merge these rows conditionally as shown in image2.

Could you please help?

Thanks :)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0wm.png)

Comment: If your data is in column a:b then  bellow code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Test this.

```
     Sub test()
        Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
        Dim rngO As Range, myCell As Range
        Dim n As Integer

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With
        Set rngDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        For Each rng In rngDB
            If rng <> "" Then
                n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, rng)
                Set rngO = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(n)
                For Each myCell In rngO
                    If myCell <> "" Then
                        myCell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngO, myCell)).Merge
                    End If
                Next myCell
                rng.Resize(n).Merge
            End If
        Next rng
         With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With

    End Sub
```

or test this

```
 Sub test2()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim rngO As Range, myCell As Range
    Dim rngU As Range, s
    Dim n As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    Set rngDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng <> "" Then
            n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, rng)
            Set rngO = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(n)
            s = rngO(1)
            For Each myCell In rngO
                If myCell <> "" Then
                    If s = myCell Then
                        If rngU Is Nothing Then
                            Set rngU = myCell
                        Else
                            Set rngU = Union(rngU, myCell)
                        End If
                    Else
                        rngU.Merge
                        Set rngU = myCell
                        s = myCell
                    End If
                End If
            Next myCell
            rngU.Merge
            Set rngU = Nothing
            rng.Resize(n).Merge
        End If
    Next rng
     With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hi Dy.Lee, test2 worked perfectly, I really appreciated it.

Comment: The thing is that I need to do this in more that one cells , for example in cell B and cell C and cell D at the same time

Comment: @NasZor, The coding depends on the type of your data. I can not answer because I do not know your data.

Answer (score 0):

Dy.Lee I really appreciated your answers, really thanks.

Sub test2() works if I have 1 column with data but what I actually want is to do this in more that one cells , for example in cell B and cell C and cell D at the same time

please check the image below

Really thanks again.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZTM.png)